# The average of reciprocal binomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, pr.probability

This question is motivated by [the MO problem here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/262474/an-identity-related-to-hankel-determinants-of-sum-k-1n-frac2kk). Perhaps it is not that difficult.

> **Question.** Here is an cute formula. 
>   $$\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{\binom{n-1}k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k2^{n-k}}.$$
>   I've one justification along the lines of Wilf-Zeilberger (see below). Can you provide an alternative proof? Or, any reference?

The claim amounts to $a_n=b_n$ where
$$a_n:=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{2^n}{n\binom{n-1}k} \qquad \text{and} \qquad
b_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^k}k.$$
Define $F(n,k):=\frac{2^n}{n\binom{n-1}k}$ and $\,G(n,k)=-\frac{2^n}{(n+1)\binom{n}k}$. Then, it is routinely checked that 
$$F(n+1,k)-F(n,k)=G(n,k+1)-G(n,k),\tag1$$ 
for instance by dividing through with $F(n,k)$ and simplifying. Summing (1) over $0\leq k\leq n-1$:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}F(n+1,k)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}F(n,k)
&=a_{n+1}-\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}-a_n, \\
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}G(n,k+1)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}G(n,k)
&=-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^n}{(n+1)\binom{n}k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{2^n}{(n+1)\binom{n}k}=0. \end{align}
Therefore, $a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}$. But, it is evident that $b_{n+1}-b_n=\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}$. Since $a_1=b_1$, it follows $a_n=b_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

=====================================

Here is an alternative approach to Fedor's answer below in his elaboration of Fry's comment.

With $\frac1{n+1}\binom{n}k=\int_0^1x^{n-k}(1-x)^kdx$, we get $a_{n+1}=2^{n+1}\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^nx^{n-k}(1-x)^kdx$. So,
\begin{align}
2^{n+1}\int_0^1 dx\sum_{k=0}^nx^{n-k}(1-x)^k
&=2^{n+1}\int_0^1x^ndx\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{1-x}x\right)^k \\
&=2^{n+1}\int_0^1x^n\frac{\left(\frac{1-x}x\right)^{n+1}-1}{\frac{1-x}x-1}dx \\
&=\int_0^1\frac{(2-2x)^{n+1}-(2x)^{n+1}}{1-2x}\,dx:=c_{n+1}.
\end{align}
Let's take successive difference of the newly-minted sequence $c_{n+1}$:
\begin{align}
c_{n+1}-c_n
&=\int_0^1\frac{(2-2x)^{n+1}-(2-2x)^n+(2x)^n-(2x)^{n+1}}{1-2x}\,dx \\
&=\int_0^1\left[(2-2x)^n+(2x)^n\right]dx=2^{n+1}\int_0^1x^ndx=\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}. \end{align}
But, $b_{n+1}-b_n=\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}$ and hence $a_n=b_n$.

Comment: I think that you should be able to proved it by using the identity $1/((n+1)\binom{n}{k}) = \int_0^1 x^{n-k}(1-x)^k dx$ and interchanging the summation and the integral.

Comment: If you simply want a reference, see (2.18) of http://www.math.wvu.edu/~gould/Vol.3.PDF.

Comment: @RichardStanley: Thank you, indeed. It'd be a plus, too, if we can see different or novel proofs here.

Comment: See, for instance, @robjohn's post at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151441/calculate-sums-of-inverses-of-binomial-coefficients

Comment: @darijgrinberg: I appreciate the direction, it was nice too. Thanks.

Comment: @Fry: Your approach is quite appealing, I wish you could iron out the details as it might be instructional. I already posted mine. For instance, interchanging $\int$ and $\sum$ brings you to $\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)^{n+1}-x^{n+1}}{1-2x}d$. Must show this equals $\frac1{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{2^k}k$.

Comment: I wonder if there is a probabilistic interpretation. Choose a number $k$ from $[0,n-1]$, uniformly at random.  Then choose  a $k$-subset of $\lbrace 0,\ldots,n-1\rbrace$, uniformly at random.  Then the left side is the probability you chose a leading subset of $\lbrace 0,\ldots,n-1\rbrace$.  The question is how to interpret the right side as the same probability.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay: I like that. What is "a leading subset"?

Comment: A leading subset is one of the form $\lbrace 0,1,\ldots,j\rbrace$ for some $j$.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/146285/2-adic-logarithm-and-resistance-of-n-dimensional-cube

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov: Yes, that is related. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As in the question
$$a_n:=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{2^n}{n\binom{n-1}k} \qquad \text{and} \qquad
b_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^k}k.$$
It is clear that $a_1=b_1$ and $b_{n+1}-b_n=\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}$. But we have the same recursive relation for $a_n$ because
\begin{align}
a_n&=2^n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{k!(n-1-k)!(k+1+n-k)}{n!(n+1)} \\
&=2^n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{(k+1)!(n-1-k)!}{(n+1)!}+\frac{k!(n-k)!}{(n+1)!}\right) \\
&=2^n\left(2\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{k!(n-k)!}{(n+1)!}-\frac{2}{n+1}\right)=a_{n+1}-\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 7):

Let me elaborate on Fry's suggestion and your forthcoming comment.

$$\frac1{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{2^k}k=\frac1{2^{n+1}}\int_0^2(1+x+\dots+x^n)dx=\frac1{2^{n+1}}\int_0^2\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}dx=\\2\int_{0}^1\frac{(1/2)^{n+1}-t^{n+1}}{1-2t}dt=2\int_{0}^1\frac{(1-s)^{n+1}-(1/2)^{n+1}}{1-2s}ds.$$
We used change of variables $x=2t$, $s=1-t$. Now take a half-sum of two last expressions (identifying $t$ and $s$), you get
$$
\int_{0}^1\frac{(1-t)^{n+1}-t^{n+1}}{1-2t}dt=\sum_{k=0}^n\int_0^1(1-t)^kt^{n-k}dt=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{(n+1)\binom{n}k}.
$$